# Problemas con Manifest debug Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, android-manifest

No se por qué me empezo a ponr por consola esto y me salta el android manifest del builder... que sucede. Estaba intentando quitar la barra de arriba que traen las apps por defecto que pone el nombre del projecto poniendo esto en el manifest normal.

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

y me salta error en este manifest que esta en otra ubicacion

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.turespawn"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="22"
    android:targetSdkVersion="31" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:testOnly="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TuRespawn" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.turespawn.HomeActivity"
        android:exported="true" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.turespawn.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

me aparecen estos errores
[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que actualmente estos valores que defines dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
android:minSdkVersion="22"
android:targetSdkVersion="31"
```

deben ser definidos ùnicamente dentro del archivo `build.gradle` de tu proyecto, dentro del bloque `defaultConfig`.

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        ...
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 31
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Entonces los quito de ahi y los meto al buil.gradle?

Comment: Si, únicamente en el build.gradle vuelve a construir el proyecto para revisar que otros errores continúan generandose.